# Не отображаются изображения в HTML рассылках на iPhone

Tags: html, вёрстка, email, вёрстка-email

Подскажите, в HTML рассылках на iPhone в приложении Яндекс.Почта вместо изображений пустые квадраты-заглушки. Если зайти через несколько секунд еще раз в письмо, отобразятся первые несколько изображений, а дальше квадраты. Так вот зайдем несколько раз и письмо отобразится полностью.

Отправляем клиентам рассылки, которые полностью состоят из изображений в табличной верстке (чтобы сохранить фирменный шрифт, дизайн и т.д.)

Формат такой:

```html
<table align="center" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border:0;">
<tr align="center">
<td align="center" width="34" style="text-align:center;line-height:18px;vertical-align:top;"><img alt="" style="width:34px;max-width:34px;height:auto;display:block;" src="https://сайт/image/webmails/300623/13_1.jpg" /></td> 
<td align="center" width="261" style="text-align:center;line-height:18px;vertical-align:top;"><a target="_blank" href=""><img alt="" style="width:261px;max-width:261px;height:auto;display:block;" src="https://сайт/image/webmails/300623/13_2.jpg" /></a></td>
<td align="center" width="10" style="text-align:center;line-height:18px;vertical-align:top;"><img alt="" style="width:10px;max-width:10px;height:auto;display:block;" src="https://сайт/image/webmails/300623/13_3.jpg" /></td> 
<td align="center" width="260" style="text-align:center;line-height:18px;vertical-align:top;"><a target="_blank" href=""><img alt="" style="width:260px;max-width:260px;height:auto;display:block;" src="https://сайт/image/webmails/300623/13_4.jpg" /></a></td> 
<td align="center" width="35" style="text-align:center;line-height:18px;vertical-align:top;"><img alt="" style="width:35px;max-width:35px;height:auto;display:block;" src="https://сайт/image/webmails/300623/13_5.jpg" /></td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

Проверяли на разных версиях iPhone, одинаково.
На Android/PC все хорошо.

Средний вес всех изображений для письма ~700кб + ~30кб HTML

Срабатывает какая-то блокировка от iPhone? По весу/содержимому?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если через несколько попыток начинает отображаться, то можно предположить, что проблема в сервере, который по каким-то причинам не может переварить наплыв запросов от айфона. Смотрите логи сервера в момент открытия письма